# undefined method named "render" in Listener Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on sending mail (Swift mailer) from a listener on Symfony, only I have an error when using renderView (try with render too)...

> Undefined method 'renderView'.

Here my listener :

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class UserSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => ['sendMail', EventPriorities::POST_VALIDATE],
        ];
    }

    public function sendMail(ViewEvent $event): void
    {
        $user = $event->getControllerResult();
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

        if (!$user instanceof User || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method) {
            return;
        }

        $message = (new \Swift_Message('A new book has been added'))
            ->setFrom('mail@mail.com')
            ->setTo('mail@mail.com')
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                    'emails/registration.html.twig',
                    ['userPseudo' => $user->getPseudo()]
                ),
                'text/html'
            );

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

I understand that the templating service is not available in the listener, but I don't understand how to inject it.

Comment: Inject through the `__construct`

Comment: You don't have a method `renderView()` or `render()` in your Subscriber. You have to implement it. You can look at the AbstractController from Symfony's FrameworkBundle as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency Injection  - read  about it

You need  pass Twig  to this class (just like you did  with Swift Mailer)

at the beginning :

```
use Twig\Environment;

class UserSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

private $mailer;
private $twig;

public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, Environment $environment)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->twig = $environment;
}
```

and in code (in methods) you  use it  this way :

```
$this->twig->render()
```

NOT

```
$this->renderView()
```